# How to update one dataframe using values from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two `df`s, `df1` is like,

```
primary_key    code    amount
220492763      763     32.41
213274768      764     23.41
226835769      766     88.41
224874836      7766    100.31
219074759      74836   111.33
```

`df2` is like,

```
primary_key    code    amount
213274768      764     24.41
224874836      7766    101.31
217774816      768     123.43
222176762      798     111.44
219374759      24774   134.56
```

I like to use `df2` to update `df_1` based on the same `primary_key`, and for the rest of rows in `df2`, append them to the end of `df1`, so the result looks like,

```
primary_key    code    amount
220492763      763     32.41
213274768      764     24.41
226835769      766     88.41
224874836      7766    101.31
219074759      74836   111.33
217774816      768     123.43
222176762      798     111.44
219374759      24774   134.56
```

have tried to use

```
df1.set_index('primary_key').combine_first(df2.set_index('primary_key')).reset_index()
```

but the two `df`s mixed together, I am wondering how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `combine_first`

```
yourdf=df2.set_index('primary_key').combine_first(df1.set_index('primary_key')).reset_index()
yourdf
Out[287]: 
   primary_key     code  amount
0    213274768    764.0   24.41
1    217774816    768.0  123.43
2    219074759  74836.0  111.33
3    219374759  24774.0  134.56
4    220492763    763.0   32.41
5    222176762    798.0  111.44
6    224874836   7766.0  101.31
7    226835769    766.0   88.41
```

Update adding the order

```
idx=pd.concat([df1.primary_key,df2.primary_key]).drop_duplicates()
yourdf=df2.set_index('primary_key').combine_first(df1.set_index('primary_key')).reindex(idx).reset_index()
yourdf
Out[293]: 
   primary_key     code  amount
0    220492763    763.0   32.41
1    213274768    764.0   24.41
2    226835769    766.0   88.41
3    224874836   7766.0  101.31
4    219074759  74836.0  111.33
5    217774816    768.0  123.43
6    222176762    798.0  111.44
7    219374759  24774.0  134.56
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, but the output isn't exactly what I look for.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat`, `drop_duplicates`, and `reindex`:

```
idx=pd.concat([df1.primary_key,df2.primary_key]).drop_duplicates()
pd.concat([df2,df1]).drop_duplicates('primary_key').set_index('primary_key').reindex(idx).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   primary_key   code  amount
0    220492763    763   32.41
1    213274768    764   24.41
2    226835769    766   88.41
3    224874836   7766  101.31
4    219074759  74836  111.33
5    217774816    768  123.43
6    222176762    798  111.44
7    219374759  24774  134.56
```